# Stop my link colors from changing colors?

Tags: hyperlink, colors

I have Dreamweaver CS6. How do I keep my link colors from changing colors? No choice for none. All I'm given is default which is blue and other color choices. I have it set to hover red, works fine. Any suggestions?

So far I have:

```
a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #F00
a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: none;
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid CSS. Also note there's a [`visited`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/) state.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right, add the closing `}`, if it's still not working try `color: none !important;`